# How to replace 0 or missing value with NA in R

Tags: r

this is what  i have already done so far
data is numeric data type

```
if (is.na(data) || attribute==0){replace(data,NA)}
```

it gives me error message that

> Error in replace(attribute, NA) : argument "values" is missing, with no default

Comment: You are using `replace` incorrectly.  See `help(replace)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use `replace` without any additional function / package:

```
data <- replace(data, data == 0, NA)
```

This is now assuming that `data` is your data frame.

Otherwise you can simply insert the column name, e.g. if your data frame is `df` and column name `data`:

```
df$data <- replace(df$data, df$data == 0, NA)
```

Comment: this is the best solution with base r. if someone wants a dplyr solution, then the simplest would be `df %>% map_df(~ na_if(.x, 0))`

Answer (score 11):

With `mutate_all`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_all(~replace(., . == 0, NA))
```

or with `mutate_if` to be safe:

```
df %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace(., . == 0, NA))
```

Note that there is no need to check for `NA`'s, because we are replacing with `NA` anyway.

**Output:**

```
> df %>%
+   mutate_all(~replace(., . == 0, NA))
    X  Y    Z
1   1  5 <NA>
2   4  4    2
3   2  3    2
4   5  5    2
5   5  3 <NA>
6  NA  4 <NA>
7   3  3    1
8   5  3    2
9   3  1    1
10  2 NA    5
11  5  5 <NA>
12  2  5    2
13  4  4    4
14  3  4 <NA>
15 NA NA    3
16  5  2    1
17  1  4 <NA>
18 NA  1    4
19  1  1    5
20  5  1    2

> df %>%
+   mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace(., . == 0, NA))
    X  Y Z
1   1  5 0
2   4  4 2
3   2  3 2
4   5  5 2
5   5  3 0
6  NA  4 0
7   3  3 1
8   5  3 2
9   3  1 1
10  2 NA 5
11  5  5 0
12  2  5 2
13  4  4 4
14  3  4 0
15 NA NA 3
16  5  2 1
17  1  4 0
18 NA  1 4
19  1  1 5
20  5  1 2
```

**Data:**

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(X = sample(0:5, 20, replace = TRUE),
                 Y = sample(0:5, 20, replace = TRUE),
                 Z = as.character(sample(0:5, 20, replace = TRUE)))
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to import the library you were mentioning about, because it doesn't allow me to use mutate_all. I'm testing it on R_markdown

Comment: @jdfhf `install.packages('dplyr')` then `library(dplyr)` should give you the latest version. Your version of `dplyr` is probably outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `data` is a `dataframe` then you could use `sapply` to update your values based on a set of filters:

```
new.data = as.data.frame(sapply(data,FUN= function(x) replace(x,is.na(x) | x == 0)))
```